# Client-Server Socket Programming not outputting to txt

Tags: java, sockets, io

I'm new to socket programming. I have a client that retrieves a url from a txt file on my desktop and passes it on via a socket to the server. The server retrieves the html-code of the webpage as a sting, replaces some tags in the string and sends the string (html-code) back to the client. I'm able to see the string when I output it to my console, but when I try to pass it on to a local txt/html file, I get a blank file/page. Can someone point me out to what I'm doing wrong?

Server:

```
 public class Server {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fromClient = "";
    StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder fClient = new StringBuilder();
    String str = null;
    try(ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8082)){
        System.out.println("Server started, waiting for clients...");
        while(true){
            try(Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream toClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream())){
                for(String line = inFromClient.readLine(); line != null && line.length()>0; line = inFromClient.readLine()){
                    fClient.append(line);
                }
                if(fClient.toString().contains("www.mmix.cs.hm.edu")){
                    fromClient = "www.mmix.cs.hm.edu";
                }
                try(InputStream url = new URL("http://"+fromClient+"/index.html").openStream();
                    BufferedReader getUrl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url))){
                        for(String line = getUrl.readLine(); line != null; line = getUrl.readLine()){
                            htmlCode.append(line);
                        }
                    str = htmlCode.toString();
                    String imgReplaced = replaceImgs(str);
                    String replaced = replaceYou(imgReplaced);
                    toClient.writeBytes(replaced);  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
 public class Client {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url;
    String returned;
    try(Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8082);
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\client.txt"));
        BufferedWriter toServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter toBrowser = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\MMIX.txt"))){

        url = inFromUser.readLine();
        toServer.write("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        toServer.write("Host: "+url+"\r\n");
        toServer.write("\r\n");
        toServer.flush();   

        returned = inFromServer.readLine();
        //Output to the console works
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + returned);
        //Output to the stream toBrowser which writes to a txt file, not working
        for(returned = inFromServer.readLine(); returned != null && returned.length() > 0; returned = inFromServer.readLine()){
            toBrowser.write(returned);
            System.out.println(returned);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "_when I try to pass it on to a local txt/html file_" — how exactly are you doing it?

Comment: The last for-loop on the client-side.

Comment: Do you just do shell redirection, like `java Client > some_file.txt`? And you can see the text on console, but not in the file? If so, chances are your code is fine, and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Your not closing anything. The server must close the accepted socket, and the client must close its socket and the `BufferedWriter`. Why are you stopping the loop at a blank line?

Comment: It's a try-with-resources statement, the resources will be automatically closed once the try statement is done with.
Which loop have i stopped at a blank line?